# Meta Viewport tag works on the home page but does not work on other pages

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have two web pages. First one is the home page.  The other is another page user can navigate to from the home page. 
I have used the following Meta tag to disable the zoom in and out on the home page. It works perfectly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
```

But this same tag does not work on the second page. Users can still zoom in and out the second page.
I’m using jqueryMobile on the both pages. I use the following tag on both pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

just to let the browser know that HTML5 is being used.
I'm using an ipad with iOS7.

Could someone let me know why the Meta tag doesn’t work on my second page?

Comment: how do you move to next page? have you added meta tag in next page too?

Comment: yes. I have added. I am using the EMC WDK framework. There is a method  called setNestedComponentJump. I use this method for the navigation and I found out yesterday this method is reason for this issue. Anyway I have to use this method since I'm working on a WDK webapp.  lets forget all the WDK crap for a moment. I'm just wondering what this method might be doing to nullify the effect of the meta tag, probably the whole header section on the second page. Any ideas you can think of?

Comment: @Omar, Can we add this meta tag through JS. I tried the following <script>
   $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">')
  </script> then I tried document.getElementById("vp").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'); didn't work

Comment: Are you using _multi-page model_ or _single page model_?

Comment: @Omar can u explain what multi-page model is?

Comment: Multi-page = all pages in one file. Single page = each page in a separate html file. Do you have Ajax enabled to navigate between pages?

Comment: @Omar, Thanks Omar. this is single page model. I have disabled Ajax on all pages using $.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false;   $.mobile.pushStateEnabled=false;

Comment: Then you have to add meta tag as well as js libraries in each file.

Comment: @Omar I have done that.

Comment: Same effect? Only first page works and the rest don't?

Comment: @Omar, Yes. I Can't come up with a good reason why the meta tag does not work. Like I said before it's the WDK method which is doing something to nullify this tag. I'm still wondering what this method could be doing to do so